# How do I figure out if a 'function is odd or even'?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

I am currently doing an highschool math problem and I do not know what the question is asking for when it asks '**state which functions are odd and which are even for the below**'.

- $f(x)= x^2+1 $            ,
  Dom: $x : R$
- $h(x)= 1/(x^2)$           ,
  Dom: $x ≠  0$
- $g(x)= x$                 ,
  Dom: $x : R$
- $K(x)= 1/x$               ,
  Dom: $x ≠  0$

- What can I do to find out if a function is odd or even?
- What is the definition of an odd function and an even function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found an explanation that was really clear, and it seem to complement the answer that Mahidevran gave.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is $\mathbf{even}$ if $F(x) = F(-x)$ for all $x$.

$F$ is $\mathbf{odd}$ if $F(-x) = - F(x) $ for all $x$

$\mathbf{Homework}$: Are there functions that are both even and odd?. [Hint: There is exactly one.]

Comment: What's going on?

Comment: sexual healing..

Comment: Everything, man!

Comment: what's up baby?

Comment: So , do I have to substitute a number into the equation and see if the result is a negative

Comment: sure. For example, suppose $f(x) = x^2$. Since $f(-x) = (-x)^2 = (-x)(-x)= x^2 = f(x)$, we conclude that $f(x) = x^2$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

substitute $-x$ on the function. That is if $f(-x) = f(x)$ then even, if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ then odd.

1) if  $f(x) = x^{2} + 1$, then substituting $-x$ on the funciton we have $f(-x) =(-x)^{2} + 1 = x^2 + 1 = f(x)$ so even.

2) if $h(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ ,then $h(-x) = \frac{1}{(-x)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} = h(x)$. So even.

3) if $g(x) = x$, then $g(-x) = -x = -g(x)$ so odd.

4) if $k(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $k(-x) = \frac{1}{(-x)} = -\frac{1}{x} = -k(x) $
so odd.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by f(-x) = f(x) and f(-x)=-f(x)

Comment: if the function is the same when you plug in negative x, then it is an even funciton. Example f(x) = x^2 it the same when you plug in a negative since f(-x) = (-x)^2 = x^2. If the function is changed that is, you can factor a negative sign, then it is an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

Odd function graphically they are symmetric about an origin and for even function they are symmetric about the y-axis so you can see it that way...